# Module build failed: TypeError: loader.charAt is not a function

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to run the npm run dev command, but I'm getting this message:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                         21:31:43

Module build failed: TypeError: loader.charAt is not a function
    at ensureBang (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:180:16)
    at getLoaderString (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:145:18)
    at getRequireString (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:80:7)
    at getRequire (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:71:7)
    at D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:205:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:198:18)

Module build failed: TypeError: loader.charAt is not a function
    at ensureBang (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:180:16)
    at getLoaderString (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:145:18)
    at getRequireString (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:80:7)
    at getRequire (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:71:7)
    at D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:205:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports (D:\iagof\Source\Repos\todo-list\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loader.js:198:18)

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
```

This problem appeared when I tried to reinstall all the modules. Anything, my project is on Github. Follow the repository link https://github.com/iagofrota/todo-list.

Comment: The problem has something to do with vue-loader, but I'm having a hard time tracking down what. It looks like you're on vue-loader@13.5.0 (https://github.com/iagofrota/todo-list/blob/master/package-lock.json#L9856) but your error message references getLoaderString being called on line 145 when it's on line 522 from what I'm seeing (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/v13.5.0/lib/loader.js#L522). I'm missing something here. I have seen some things about past breaks due to "extract-text-webpack-plugin", but I'm not sure that's what it is.

Comment: On a hunch I just started going back versions. `vue-loader` had `getLoaderString` encompassing line 145 back in version 10 (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/v10.0.0/lib/loader.js#L128-L160). Perhaps you should nuke your node_modules folder and re`npm install`?

Comment: Some people suggested I delete the folder `node_modules` and override the `npm install` command, but it did not work.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore I want to thank you in advance for the support